# Working with scanf and floats in C

Tags: c, floating-point

I want to scan a file for 001.120 float or 220.550 or 123.125 etc., and floats with three digits, and three decimal digits, how do I do this, like is it %03.3f?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's just `%f`. It doesn't need to know the specifics because it can deduce them.

Comment: Yeah, but what if I want to make sure it prints the 00s before the 1, and after the 2. Like I want it to always be _ _ _._ _ _ format

Comment: @123456Program The appropriate response when someone answers your question is to upvote and accept. If you've got a follow-on question, start a new question. Although I suspect "how do I print a floating point number in C" already has answers.

Comment: It wont let me upvote, it says it requires 15 reputation

Comment: @123456Program you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the grey tick mark, even with low reputation